# Calculate the volume of the solid bounded by $z=x^2+y$, $z=0$ and $z=2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Calculate the volume of the solid bounded by $z=x^2+y$, $z=0$ and $z=2$

**Attempt**

Projection of the curve $\{x^2+y=z, z=2\}$ on $xy-$plane is a parabola. Thus, in order to calculate the volumen inside the surface 0, and between planes $z=0$ and $z=2$, we will calculate a double integral of a function $f(x, y)=x^2+y$ over region $D:x^2+y=2$.

$$\int \int_D x^2+y\: dxdy$$

Comment: Are you sure that the statement is correct? The solid seems to be unbounded

Comment: I noticed that, but that's how they dictated the exercise.

Comment: In my opinion a  constraint is missing. Do you have the final answer?

Comment: My first guess is that the function was supposed to be $x^2 + y^2$.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor Do you mean $z=x^2+y^2$? In that case the constraint $z=0$ is irrelevant